# Time zone in php file

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a pubDate in xml which I have to write to mysql database - everything works fine but I have a problem with the time zone:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Warsaw');
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($entry->pubDate));
```

Data in xml file:

`<pubDate>Sat, 02 Sep 2017 20:41:30 +0000</pubDate>`

Score in the database:
2017-09-02 22:41:30
As you can see the difference is two hours but I do not know what it is and how to get the correct effect.

Answer (score -1):

What is your database timezone ? try this request SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone; Maybe you also need to change your mysql timezone

Comment: returns SYSTEM SYSTEM - The system time zone is well set.

Comment: something wrong with this notation <pubDate>Sat, 02 Sep 2017 20:41:30 +0000</pubDate> . it should be <pubDate>Sat, 02 Sep 2017 20:41:30 +01</pubDate>

Answer (score -1):

You have to set the timezone for mysql too.